# How to transfer data from/with PrivateTempStore?

Tags: 8, forms

I have an multistepform which handles sessions and stores like this:
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-multi-step-forms-in-drupal-8/

But i want the option that the user can login in between. The previous input is lost if i wouldn't do anything, because the form is creating a new private store. At the moment i save the relevant data in extra cookies and retrieve them after the login succeeded.

Is there a better way to transfer the data between the stores or am I missing something?

Best Regards 
FirstSanny

Comment: I wouldn't store data in the private tempstore for anonymous users. Store the data in the session directly and it will be preserved when the user logs in.

Comment: @4k4 Do you mean to store it directly in the $_SESSION variable? I thought that is bad practice for Drupal sites?!

Comment: Yes, it is, but you don't need to replace it with PrivateTempStore. Session is still available, now in a symfony object. See the answer.

Comment: BTW there was an issue with starting a session for Drupal sites, which were installed or updated via composer since April 2, 2019. Fixed by [Drupal 8.6.14](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.6.14).

Comment: @4k4 good to know and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Access session data through the Request object](https://www.drupal.org/node/2380327):

**Drupal 7:**

```
function mymodule_session_counter_increment() {
  if (!isset($_SESSION['mymodule_count'])) {
    $_SESSION['mymodule_count'] = 0;
  }

  return $_SESSION['mymodule_count']++;
}
```

**Drupal 8:**

```
class MymoduleSessionCounter {
  function increment(Request $request) {
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $value = $session->get('mymodule_count', 0);
    $session->set('mymodule_count', $value + 1);

    return $value;
  }
}
```

In procedural code you find the request here:

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
```

Session data stored for anonymous traffic is automatically migrated when a user is logging in.